# Multiple dictionary list of values assignment with a single for loop for multiple keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension

I want to create a dictionary with a list of values for multiple keys with a single for loop in Python3. For me, the time execution and memory footprint are of utmost importance since the file which my Python3 script is reading is rather long.

I have already tried the following simple script:

```
p_avg = []
p_y = []
m_avg = []
m_y = []
res_dict = {}

with open('/home/user/test', 'r') as f:
    for line in f: 
        p_avg.append(float(line.split(" ")[5].split(":")[1]))
        p_y.append(float(line.split(" ")[6].split(":")[1]))
        m_avg.append(float(line.split(" ")[1].split(":")[1]))
        m_avg.append(float(line.split(" ")[2].split(":")[1]))

res_dict['p_avg'] = p_avg
res_dict['p_y'] = p_y
res_dict['m_avg'] = m_avg
res_dict['m_y'] = mse_y

print(res_dict)
```

The format of my `home/user/test` file is:

```
n:1 m_avg:7588.39 m_y:11289.73 m_u:147.92 m_v:223.53 p_avg:9.33 p_y:7.60 p_u:26.43 p_v:24.64
n:2 m_avg:7587.60 m_y:11288.54 m_u:147.92 m_v:223.53 p_avg:9.33 p_y:7.60 p_u:26.43 p_v:24.64
n:3 m_avg:7598.56 m_y:11304.50 m_u:148.01 m_v:225.33 p_avg:9.32 p_y:7.60 p_u:26.43 p_v:24.60
.
.
.
```

The Python script shown above works but first it is too long and repetitive, second, I am not sure how efficient it is. I was eventually thinking to create the same with list-comprehensions. Something like that:

```
(res_dict['p_avg'], res_dict['p_y']) = [(float(line.split(" ")[5].split(":")[1]), float(line.split(" ")[6].split(":")[1])) for line in f]
```

But for all four dictionary keys. Do you think that using list comprehension could reduce the used memory footprint of the script and the speed of execution? What should be the right syntax for the list-comprehension?

[EDIT] I have changed the `dict` -> `res_dict` as it was mentioned that it is not a good practice, I have also fixed a typo, where the `p_y` wasn't pointing to the right value and added a print statement to print the resulting dictionary as mentioned by the other users.

Comment: Please add an example input and check the indentations in your question.  Also I do not see a `print` or anything so idk how you got your output. Please fix that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `defaultdict`. There is no need to split the line each time, and to make it more readable you can use a lambda to extract the fields for each item.

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(list)

with open('/home/user/test', 'r') as f:
    for line in f: 
        items = line.split()
        extract = lambda x: x.split(':')[1]

        res['p_avg'].append(extract(items[5]))
        res['p_y'].append(extract(items[6]))
        res['m_avg'].append(extract(items[1]))
        res['m_y'].append(extract(items[2]))
```

Comment: I agree that splitting the lines initially makes sense but isn't it possible to assign all the values of the keys with a single line

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize your `dict` to contain the string/list pairs, and then append directly as you iterate through every line. Also, you don't want to keep calling `split()` on `line` on each iteration. Rather, just call once and save to a local variable and index from this variable.

```
# Initialize dict to contain string key and list value pairs
dictionary = {'p_avg':[],
              'p_y':[],
              'm_avg':[],
              'm_y':[]
             }
with open('/home/user/test', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        items = line.split() # store line.split() so you don't split multiple times per line
        dictionary['p_avg'].append(float(items[5].split(':')[1]))
        dictionary['p_y'].append(float(items[6].split(':')[1])) # I think you meant index 6 here
        dictionary['m_avg'].append(float(items[1].split(':')[1]))
        dictionary['m_y'].append(float(items[2].split(':')[1]))
```

Comment: Yes, you are right about the dict name and yes, I meant index 6. I have simplified my program and made a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pre-define dict attributes:

```
d = {
    'p_avg': [],
    'p_y': [],
    'm_avg': [],
    'm_y': []
}
```

and then append directly to them:

```
with open('/home/user/test', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        splitted_line = line.split(" ")
        d['p_avg'].append(float(splitted_line[5].split(":")[1]))
        d['p_y'].append(float(splitted_line[5].split(":")[1]))
        d['m_avg'].append(float(splitted_line[1].split(":")[1]))
        d['m_avg'].append(float(splitted_line[2].split(":")[1]))
```

---

P.S. Never use variable names equal to built-in words, like `dict`, `list` etc. It can cause MANY various errors!